# Cakephp CakeTime DST handling

Tags: cakephp, date, time, timezone, dst

I store all dates in UTC in my database. Cakephp runs in UTC and communicates with mysql in UTC. Now i have following scenario:

```
debug(CakeTime::format('Y-m-d H:i', '2013-03-22 03:00', false,
    new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin')));
//output is 2013-03-22 04:00

debug(CakeTime::format('Y-m-d H:i', '2013-04-05 03:00', false,
    new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin')));
//output is 2013-04-05 05:00
```

As you can see CakeTime added 2 hours of offset in the second example, i guess that is because it considers DST (starting at 31.03.2013).
However what i am trying to do is displaying recurring events in a calendar and this event starts each second Friday at 4am - always, even in summer. Therefore the calendar may not display it to be at 5am!

/EDIT: the first example is corret. the event has to be at 4am. but also in summer

Comment: Have you used `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` and `Configure::write('Config.timezone', 'UTC');` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using these two functions for time converting.
Keep in mind that this is for recurring events, that start always at the same time of day(e.g. 4am) regardless of DST.

```
public function dateTimeToSever($date, $user_timezone) {
    $DateTime = new DateTime($date, $user_timezone);
    $dst = $DateTime->format('I');
    $toServerDateTime = CakeTime::toServer($date, $user_timezone, 'Y-m-d H:i');
    if ($dst) {
        $toServerDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($toServerDateTime . ' + 1 Hours'));
    }
    return $toServerDateTime;
}

public function dateTimeToUser($date, $user_timezone) {
    $DateTime = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $DateTime->setTimezone($user_timezone);
    $dst = $DateTime->format('I');
    $userDateTime = CakeTime::format('Y-m-d H:i', $date, false, $user_timezone);
    if ($dst) {
        $userDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($userDateTime . ' - 1 Hours'));
    }
    return $userDateTime;
}
```

This should work for all timezones that use *positive* DST. AFAIK some timezones, e.g. somewhere in North India, have some kind of *negative* timezone. I guess in that case the "+ 1 Hours" has to become "- 1 Hours" and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are getting the wrong time in both cases.  If you want to store all your dates in UTC then you need to make sure you store the correct UTC values for the timezone the user is in.  For example, if you want a reoccurring event every Friday at 3pm in the Europe/Berlin timezone, then do the following.

```
// save your date like this
$date = new DateTime('2013-04-05 03:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
$utc = $date->getTimestamp();
// print them correctly like this
$utc = CakeTime::format('Y-m-d H:i', $utc, false, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
```

On caveat to this approach, if a user changes their timezone from one with DST to one without (or vice-versa), they may encounter the same problem.

Comment: I stored it another way. Why should it not work like this? CakeTime::toServer('2013-03-22 03:00', $this->Auth->user('timezone'))

Comment: Using CakeTime::toServer converts the datetime to the servers timezone which might not be UTC.

Comment: But i have date_default_timezone_set('UTC'), Configure::write('Config.timezone', 'UTC') and $this->query("SET time_zone = '+00:00'"). So my cake and server should run in UTC and toServer() should convert it correctly to UTC. And i think it does! The problem is only the DST.